# Shifting text using CSS

Tags: css, asp.net

Using this code:

```
       <div class="details">
            <strong>Publisher:</strong>
            <span class="red"><asp:Label ID="LabelPublisher" runat="server"></asp:Label></span>
       </div>

       <div class="details">
            <strong>Author:</strong>
            <span class="red"><asp:Label ID="LabelAuthor" runat="server"></asp:Label></span>
       </div>

       <div class="details">
            <strong>Year:</strong>
            <span class="red"><asp:Label ID="LabelYear" runat="server"></asp:Label></span>
       </div>
```

...text on browser appears like this:

Publisher: publisher1
Author: author1
Year: 2014

Now using CSS I want to shift text like this on each label:

Publisher:`---`Publisher1
Author:`-----`Author1
Year:`------` 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give fixed min width to `strong` tag

```
.details strong {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1e68nvyu/)**

Answer (score 0):

You should use a table for displaying text in that way.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/h8tshvty/

```
<table>
        <tr class="details">
            <td><strong>Publisher:</strong></td>
            <td class="red">Publishername</td>
       </tr>

       <tr class="details">
            <td><strong>Author:</strong></td>
            <td class="red">Author name</td>
       </tr>

       <tr class="details">
            <td><strong>Year:</strong></td>
            <td class="red">Yearnumber</td>
       </tr>
</table>
```